# How to find an eigenvalue of a linear operator given $\lambda = 3$ is already an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$ be a selfajoint operator such that $T(2, -1) = (-8-3i, -14-6i)$ and $\lambda = 3$ is an eigenvalue. The other eigenvalue of the operator is?

This problem was posted to me by my linear-algebra teacher and I'm looking for tips that can guide me to an answear. I tried to use the fact that every eigenvalue of a selfadjoint operator is real, but I don't know how to use the given eigenvalue to find the other one.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Please click on *edit* to add more details and context: where did you encounter this problem (provide the source of the question); if you've worked on the problem, please show your effort; we can help you move on at the point you are stuck.  But as is, it looks like a copy/paste from an assigned exercise, or text exercise, quiz, or exam.  Please include more information.

Comment: E.g., some suggestions: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|128.0500).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $A$ be the matrix representing $T$ with respect to the standard basis. Since $T$ is self-adjoint, this means that the matrix $A$ is self-adjoint. So write
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} x & a + ib \\ a - ib & y \end{pmatrix} $$
where $x,y,a,b$ are real. You are given that
$$ A \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -8 - 3i \\ -14 -6i \end{pmatrix}. $$
Expanding, you get a linear system of equations for $x,a,b,y$ which has a one-dimensional space of solutions. Now use the fact that $\lambda = 3$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ to determine $A$ completely and discover the other eigenvalue.